# swiftUI Table - Context Menu disabled

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to add a `.contextMenu` to my `Table` in my macOS app.
No matter what I try the buttons in the menu stay disabled.

[image]

I use the following code

```
    @ViewBuilder
    func TableView() -> some View {
        
        // Lazy VStack
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Table(selection: $selection) {
                
                TableColumn("Name") {
                    Text($0.name)
                }.width(300)
                
                TableColumn("Filter ID") {
                    Text("\($0.id)")
                }.width(50)
                
                
            } rows: {
                ForEach(jiraFilterViewModel.filter) {
                    TableRow($0)
                }
            }
            .tableStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
            .contextMenu(
                ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Label("Do something", image: "house").disabled(false)
                })
            ).disabled(false)
            .onAppear {
                
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await jiraFilterViewModel.populate()
                    } catch (let error) {
                        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any advices?

Comment: It's the same behavior as `NSMenuItem`. You need an action to enable the menu item for example with a button.

Comment: ```.contextMenu(menuItems: {
                Button("Delete") {
                    print("Test")
                }
            })```
should do the job right? but it is still enabled.